# Understanding Blazor props syntax

Tags: razor, blazor, blazor-client-side

I know `C#` but been mostly programming `React` lately, I'm now looking at `Blazor` and trying to understand its quirky syntax.

I'm seeing in different examples that when passing props (attributes) to components an `@` sign is being used in various locations:

examples I've seen:

- before attribute value, inside quotes
  `<Component title="@SomeValue"/>`
- before attribute value, no quotes
  `<Component title=@SomeValue/>`
- before attribute name
  `<Component @title="SomeValue"/>`

What are these? I noticed that having no `@` often works the same as with it. [Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#component-parameters) doesn't go to depth re this

Answer (score 3):

> I'm seeing in different examples that when passing props (attributes) to components an @ sign is being used in various locations

Yes, this has changed a few times over the preview releases. As a consequence, some blogs and samples will be out of date. So first thing to check: how old is this code or article?

The official docs don't talk about those changes but they are up to date with the latest version.

The main changes were in [preview6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-and-blazor-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-6/) : "In this Blazor release we’ve standardized on a common syntax for directive attributes."

My simple summary: Blazor attributes (directives) start with `@`, normal HTML attributes do not.
The values of those attributes (binding or eventhandler) do not need a `@`

In a later preview it was determined that attibutes should be case-sensitive.